# Is it possible to have merge multiple mongodb into one box

Tags: mongodb

I have several boxes running their own instances of mongo, so far I have around 2 gigs of data on each one of them. I have one box where I am now beginning to route all the data to, but I have to "merge" and aggregate the data from these boxes back to this one consolidated box.

What I'm doing for each of the boxes is I'm running

```
mongodump mydb restorepath
```

and then running a mongorestore in my bigger box after transfering the bson output. Is there another way to do this? I'm afraid that I may run into problems when doing this, like id collisions, and what have you.

Comment: Those smaller machines run different copies of the same database? Or different databases?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev they run the same collections and same database, but different "data", the documents are different.

Comment: If you use Mongo's standard _id generator then you shouldn't see any collisions as they are UUIDs

Comment: @Martin even if they're two separate databases? Say DB1 stores a document, and DB2 stores a different document, aren't the chances pretty high for them having the same ID since they are unaware of each other's context?

Comment: ObjectIds contain a machine identifier, so it is unlikely there were be a collision of Ids, see https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/

Comment: ok, so it sounds like it's perfectly safe to do it the way that I'm envisioning it. Hopefully I don't run into any problems, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Id collisions when importing documents from multiple machines are very unlikely, because 3 byte of the [ObjectId](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/) represent a machine identifier of the system which generated the id. The chance of two systems having the same ObjectId is one in 16 million. Even when you run two MongoDB instances on the same machine (which you would not do, unless you want to experiment with sharding and replication) you won't get collisions, because the process ID is also a part of the ObjectId.

All of this does of course only apply when you let MongoDB generate the ObjectId's itself. It is also possible for your applications to set the `_id` field to an own value. This value doesn't even need to be an ObjectId. It can be literally any value MongoDB supports.